# Django - using Foreign key mode attribute

Tags: python, django

I have two Django models and connected via Foreignkey element and in the second model I need to use the firs model's attribute - example (pseudocode):

```
Class Category(models.Model):
      c_attribute = "Blue"

Class Object(models.Model):
      o_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
      o_color = o_category.c_attribute
```

The key here is the last line - I got error saying that ForeignKey object has no attribute c_attribute.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Because **o_category is a Key** to a **Category**, **not a Category itself**!
you can check by `type(o_category)` to check is not Category!
so you have access to related Cateogry of a Object in other parts of application when connected to database.for example in shell you can write:

```
c = Category()
c.save()
o  = Object(o_category = c, ...)  #create Object with desired params
... #some changes to o
o.save()
o.o_category.c_attribute #this will work! :)
```

Comment: Make 100% sense but is there any way how to make it working? I need to have something like pre-populated attribute of the Object model at the time I select related Categori in Administration for example.

Comment: Have seen this but it's all about playing with instances - I need to get that Category model attribute value during Object model creation/definition :(

Comment: I don't know how to do this in model.py ! may be possible but I think you can change your design!

Comment: for example put **o_color** blank during creation, then by querying as i said, fill o_colors :D ! i'm not sure! just trying to help :D

Comment: OK. I''ll try to be more specific - I do have a model Root where I have an attribute which contains some directory on the filesystem.
Then I have a model Data where I need to fill in attribute with list of all subdirectories based on the foreing keyed Rood object's parameter .

Answer (score 0):

You can use `to_field=''`, but that might give you an error as well.

```
Class Object(models.Model):
      o_category = models.ForeignKey(Category)
      o_color = models.ForeignKey(Category, to_field="c_attribute")
```

The best thing is do create a function in your Object model, that would get you the categories `c_attribute` like so:

```
def get_c_attribute(self):
    return self.o_category.c_attribute
```

Comment: I've tried the "get" function too, but problem is that I need to use that value to set returned value within the same model which is not possible due to "self is not defined" error (which make sense as there is no instance of that class yet.

Comment: @TomášCigánek sorry I made a mistake, the funciton should return `self.o_category.c_attribute`